# Transfer rows between two similar data grids (using Kendo UI) in Angular components

Tags: angular, user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I was looking at this link [Drag and drop between two kendo grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885489/drag-and-drop-between-two-kendo-grids/50247355?noredirect=1#comment87512060_50247355) for transfer of rows between grids. I searched Telerik's website https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid and could not find an equivalent in Angular components.. (typescript), any help please? (Pls be kind i am new here). I managed to implement a drag and drop in the same grid.

Comment: Have a look at reordering of rows. Maybe you can utilize that to drag/drop rows between data tables. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/advanced-features/row-reordering/

Comment: This is drag and drop in the same grid. How do we do between two similar data grid. the source of the second grid is the row we dragged in the first grid. The example I saw refers to JS in HTML (above)